# TV identification: Short-lived TV show about a time traveller with a super-computer disguised as a credit-card

Tags: story-identification, time-travel, tv

It might have only been a pilot or a made for TV movie, but I remember a male time traveller who was for some reason in 90s US from a semi-distant future. He had in his possession a super-computer disguised as a regular credit card, which could hack things and I think spoke to him in a female voice.

Note: *Not* Quantum Leap - the time traveller and "credit card computer" might be keywords that people would hit upon, but 'Ziggy' the computer in QL was non-speaking, operated by a hologram and did not resemble a credit card - this one had its own voice and was disguised as a CC.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

This is [***Time Trax***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_Trax).

> He [Darien Lambert] is assisted by the Specified Encapsulated Limitless Memory Archive,
>   or SELMA, an extremely small but very powerful computer (described as
>   equivalent to a mainframe) disguised for the mission as a credit card;
>   SELMA communicates through a holographic interface which takes the
>   visual form of a prim young woman.

"Short lived" is a bit harsh. It ran for two seasons.

Comment: Great series. The OP asked if it might have been the pilot for a movie. Time Trax first aired in 1993, and a year later the movie 'Timecop' was released with a very similar premise, although it was based on a 1992 comic which may have also been the inspiration for Time Trax. Both the series and the movie starred Mia Sara.

Comment: Definitely Time Trax. I loved that series! It's available on DVD (I own both seasons).

Comment: "A lawman *who must pursue into the past*"? Interesting, that's *not* how I remember that narrative. In https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Kj0CJ9m1ZHk, it's "a lawman *with a mission*".

Comment: Was there some TV rule that the protagonist of the "Hidden AI sidekick" SF genre had to be played by an [actor whose name ended in two "F"s](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Hasselhoff#Knight_Rider)?